# Typesetting Math using MathJax for IPython Notebook Web page

Tags: html, latex, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I chose to learn to write mathematical expressions in IPython Notebook and sat to explore learning resources. I found this [official link](http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Math_in_IPyNB_2m15.html).

I reproduced the whole tutorial on my IPython NoteBook locally and then published it on my [website](http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Math_in_IPyNB_2m15.html). I also explained the whole struggle I went into while trying to achieve this in my blog post.

Unfortunately, whatever I do, I am not able to get the web page render/display the **math expressions** *at all*. I am not sure why the whole notebook failed to show the display of equations when the last couple cells gave the right output.

I also checked both the html codes of the source [web page](http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Math_in_IPyNB_2m15.html) and my [web page](http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Math_in_IPyNB_2m15.html) to find that the `<script>` code is where it has to be in mine.

I do not know JavaScript and L<sub>A</sub>T<sub>E</sub>X at all! Can someone help please!

Again, [this](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/adrn/ipython/blob/2.x/examples/Notebook/Typesetting%20Math%20Using%20MathJax.ipynb) is the **Source link**.
And [this](http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Math_in_IPyNB_2m15.html) is **my webpage** where I copied the source tutorial.

Also, is the `ipython nbconvert` the best and the right way to convert `.ipynb` files into `html`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you face is that currently pandoc (the document converter) strips raw latex when converting the markdown cells to html, see [docu](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#raw-tex). Math in pandoc needs to be inside `$..$` or `$$..$$` delimiters.
The last couple of cells have explicit `$s` and thus convert fine. The other cells don't have this latex markup and thus get stripped during the conversion. You can try to embed the not working equations in `$$s` to prevent their removal (not tested).

There is a very recent [PR](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/commit/4f0c5c30809f09bd700cd47035f86a3db1c64669) to pandoc, to not strip raw latex when converting to html if the `--mathjax` option is supplied. Nevertheless, it will take some time to get this feature available unless you build pandoc from source.

And yes, nbconvert is the right (and best) tool to convert .ipynb files to html!

Comment: Thanks a lot @jakob . `$$` trick just worked perfect. This point was actually mentioned by the source author himself. But I couldn't give it any attention out of my ignorance. Thanks a lot. And I will sure add this point to my struggle story. Here is the refined page. http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Math_in_IPyNB_2m15.html

Comment: Sorry @Jakob. I preferred to change the whole file name. So here is the path to the modified html file. http://pyas.me/ipynbv/Write_Math_in_IPyNB_2mar15.html. And thanks again!

Comment: `$..$` will not be converted but `$$...$$` will be converted correctly, not yet test colorful formula, might refer to https://rpubs.com/englianhu/QED_DJI_calibration_Coursera_course_4ipynb